# How to send Map<String,bool> to cloud Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

We have a Map declared as follows:

```
Map<String, bool> _selection = {};
```

It contains data as follows:

```
key = 'Messi'

value = 'true'
```

We wanted to send the data containing in the Map _selection.

Right now we are trying using a method defined as given below:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> votedown() async {
      
_selection.forEach((key, value) {

        Map<dynamic, dynamic> comdata = <dynamic, dynamic>{

         'criteriaName': key,
          'isChecked': value,
        };
        return comdata;

      });
    }
```

We are sending data to firestore as:

```
 DocumentReference ref =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').doc();
 
    await ref.set({
      'Players': {
        'Football': {
         await votedown(),
        }
      }
    });
```

But it is giving error as:

```
ArgumentError (Invalid argument: Instance of '_CompactLinkedHashSet<Map<String, dynamic>>')
```

Please help me to solve this?

Desired Output in Firestore in 'posts' collection:

```
--> Players

 --> Football

  --> PlayerName : Messi

      isStriker : true
```

Comment: Can you explain the idea of what you want to do in general (voting, players, striker) ? ? Then I will help you design firebase a little better, cause even your architecture is not the best.

Comment: We are getting details of Player name in a list view stored as a Map in Firestore and there is a checkbox against each entry in UI. Now user can select any player entry by selecting the checkbox and taps on a Proceed button. We wanted to store the selected entries in Firestore on Proceed button tap.

Comment: ok, for that task you can start first by creating `Player` collection. there you would include details about each player.
Then you have `User` collection, and inside there you can have a list `[selectedPlayers] `where you would include the UID of players from other collection. write the whole question in detail and ping me here, so I can give an answer

Comment: @Tree So the collection now will be :-
Players
 'PlayerInfoMap' :
        "playerName" : Messi
        "isStriker" : true
uid: "some random String"

Other collection will be "Users":
   "SelectedPlayer":
         "playerName": Messi
          "isStriker": true.

But my question is what will be the firestore query and how we will get the data from the checkbox listile.?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in brackets `{}` surrounding the `await downvote()`. As the method is returning a map object already, if you put into the brackets you will have set of map nested object. Such objects are not in types available in the Firestore ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)) and this is reason of the error.

I do not have a playground to test it, but please try bellow:

```
 DocumentReference ref =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').doc();
 
    await ref.set({
      'Players': {
        'Football': await votedown(),
      }
    });
```

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor It did get saved in firestore , but under Football , it saves as null. Below is my votedown() function :-

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> votedown() async {
      _selection.forEach((key, value) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> comdata = <dynamic, dynamic>{
         'playerName': key,
          'isStriker': value,
        };
        return comdata;

      });
    }

Why its not sending the values , even though I am getting key values when I debugged it.?

Comment: We are able to save the data by looping map data in forEach loop and saving the key and values in a List<Map<String,bool>>. Then passed the key value pairs and add into the List<Map<key,value>> and then returned this to the firestore.